# svn says conflicted but it's really merged (TortoiseSVN)

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Lately I've been seeing behavior where after an update svn shows certain files as "conflicted" but when I try to edit the conflicts, there are none (The "next conflict" and "previous conflict" buttons are disabled and if I scroll through the file, none of the lines are marked red).

This seems to have started after I started working from a different repository than I had been working with, but I'm not sure if that's related.

Comment: When all else fails, try deleting your working copy and check out a new one.

Comment: This have happened to me as well. Try export all files and import them back in... That is my solution, quite a dumb one nevertheless :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `svn resolved` to remove the conflict markers if they're there in error.

> `resolved`: Remove 'conflicted' state on working copy files or directories.
>   usage: `resolved PATH...`
>
> Note:  this subcommand does not semantically resolve conflicts or
>     remove conflict markers; it merely removes the conflict-related
>     artifact files and allows `PATH` to be committed again.

Comment: The TortoiseSVN shell extension should offer a "Mark as resolved" option in the context menu to perform this operation

Answer (score 1):

Go to the options in TortoiseMerge and make sure that

- you don't ignore eols
- you don't ignore any whitespaces

I'm pretty sure the conflict exists in either eols or whitespaces.